# QSqlRelation is not working

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

Here is my code:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db1);
model->setTable("syllabi");
model->select();
model->setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("teacher_id", "teachers", "teacher_name"));
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
qDebug() << model->lastError();
```

I'm trying to substitute the teacher_id column with teacher_name from the 'teachers' table, but it still shows the teacher_id column. Debug shows this:

> QSqlError("", "", "")

Column information:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP83F.png

Comment: Database table column info might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
model->setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("teachers", "teacher_id", "teacher_name"));
model->select();
```

select() after setRealation()

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlrelation.html#QSqlRelation-2) states:

> QSqlRelation::QSqlRelation(const QString & tableName, const QString & indexColumn, const QString & displayColumn)
>
> Constructs a QSqlRelation object, where tableName is the SQL table name to which a foreign key refers, indexColumn is the foreign key, and displayColumn is the field that should be presented to the user.

So you seem to have mixed up the order of the string arguments, it should probably be:

```
model->setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("teachers", "teacher_id" "teacher_name"));
```